# why padding not working in cards

Tags: css, materialize, responsive

i am newbie to web development and i am working on materialize cards.It is working correctly in laptop but when i try to run it in iPad the cards are getting overlap.

```css
.container-fluid {
  margin-top: 500px;
  /*
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
*/
}

.card-reveal {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}

div.card-reveal span.card-title {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.card {
  width: 280px;
  height: 360px;
  z-index: 5 background-color: blue;
}

#card-img {
  height: 200px;
}

.card-content {
  margin-top: -17px;
  color: black;
}

.card-action {
  margin-top: 38px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stackcss.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col m3">
        <div class="card hover-reveal sticky-action z-depth-2">
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img id="card-img" class="activator z-depth-5" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/720x405/1889670.jpg">
          </div>

          <div id="thumbnail" class="z-depth-5"></div>

          <div class="card-content">
            <p><a href="#">Card Title</a><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></p>
            <!--<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 ">THis is a link</span>-->
          </div>

          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#!" id="card-parti" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal">VIEW</a>
          </div>

          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col m3">
        <div class="card hover-reveal sticky-action z-depth-2">
          <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">
            <img id="card-img" class="activator z-depth-5" src="http://images.media-allrecipes.com/userphotos/720x405/1889670.jpg">
          </div>

          <div id="thumbnail" class="z-depth-5"></div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p><a href="#">Card Title</a><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></p>
            <!--<span class="card-title activator grey-text text-darken-4 ">THis is a link</span>-->
          </div>

          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#!" id="card-parti" class="btn waves-effect waves-teal">VIEW</a>
          </div>

          <div class="card-reveal">
            <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4">Card Title<i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
            <p>Here is some more information about this product that is only revealed once clicked on.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

      <script src="js/matjs.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: card in ipad]

Comment: Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try replacing padding with margin

Comment: @Cheslab i have added the code.

Comment: I can see you forgot to close 2 divs: `.row` and `.container-fluid`. They are probably should be closed right before `</body>`

Comment: @Cheslab i tried it but the still it shows the same thing

Comment: Your code as it is now is not complete enough to reproduce the problem

Comment: @Cheslab i have put all the code for the cards. i am not putting full html code as it messing a lot in stackoverflow.i am giving the github link for my project.please check this and check my mistake if any.                            https://github.com/arunoday153/startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to have four cards in a line, each of the cards is 280px wide, and that makes it 1120px of total width. In addition, you have 50px of left and right margins (`.container-fluid`), which will add a 100px to the total width. Eventually you are going to have some space between those cards, so add another hundred. 1320px of total width for this section is a minimum that will allow you to have four of these cards in a line. According to the [Materialize documentation](http://materializecss.com/grid.html#grid-responsive) the `.m3` class that you’ve assigned to your cards will keep all these cards in a `.row` in a single line up until your screen resolution greater than 600px wide, otherwise all cards will be rearranged to fill multiple lines.

Basic on what materialize is offering you can change `.m3` classes to `.xl3` and thereby buy another 600px. But your 1320px section is still be wider than 1200px for `.xl` class, so you may consider to reduce `.container-fluid`’s left and right margins and/or reduce card’s width.

Comment: how to make my card layout adjusted to screen. as you can see there were 4 cards which were aligned in a row correctly when viewed in laptop but when screen size reduces the card comes one above another.so how would i make my card layout adjusted to screen size such that in mobile it looks the same way as it looks in the laptop screen.

Comment: Do you want to keep four cards in a row on mobile devices too?

Comment: Change classes to `.s3`

Comment: i tried it before but all the cards are getting overlapped.i tried it again but the result remains same.

Comment: `.s3` has `width: 25%`, but `.card` has `width: 280px`. Set the last one to 100%